# Sort Column code from record macro doesn't work correctly

Tags: excel, vba, filter, conditional-formatting

I recorded a macro to filter a column of numbers and text. The numbers are formatted to have a green-yellow-red colour scale with 1 as red. The only text is "VIP" which has the cell coloured in black.

The macro I recorded just uses sort by colour - black to put "VIP" at the top followed by 1 and so on, this works using the filter manually but when I use the macro it puts 1 first then "VIP" then 2 and so on. This only happens on one sheet though, the other sheets have the same code but with different sheet names and they work fine.

I'm not sure what could cause this, my recorded macro code is below:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Characterisation").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Characterisation").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("D14"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue. _
    Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Characterisation").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just randomly shooting. Can you do something like this:

```
Activesheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Activesheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("D14"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue. _
    Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
With Activesheet.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Save the code in a module. If it does not work, a few screenshots with explanations would be a good idea to help.
What I have done is to reference always the activesheet.

Comment: I've tried this but it's not working, I would upload screenshots but the file is confidential unless you want more of the code I have for it?

Comment: I've just tried using another filter and it still doesn't work, I'm thinking it's actually a problem with the top cell or row which is stopping it from being sorted.

Comment: Well, @Tom, my code changes only the current sheet to the active one. It should be working at all sheets, where your other code was working. Concerning the confidential data - do not upload it anywhere.